# Show the equivalence of two electrostatic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy

> $$U = \frac{1}{2}\iint_{all space}^{ } \frac{\rho(1)\rho(2)}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r_{12}}dV_{1}dV_{2} $$ and $$U = \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}\int_{allspace}^{ } \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E} dV.$$

In the left equation, the energy can also be described with the potential $ \phi $ where

$U = \frac{1}{2}\int_{allspace }^{ } \rho\phi dV$

because $ \rho = - \epsilon_{0} \triangledown ^{2} \phi $

plug that in

$U = -\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}\int_{allspace }^{ } \phi \triangledown^{2}\phi dV$

This is where I'm stuck.

I think you can change $ \phi \triangledown^{2}\phi$ into a form of

$ \triangledown\phi \cdot \triangledown\phi  $

such that

$\triangledown\phi  = \vec{E} $

Thus satisfying the question. However, I'm not too clear of that.

$ \phi \triangledown^{2}\phi => \triangledown\phi \cdot \triangledown\phi  $

I don't think I know any vector properties that allow this. or at LEAST

$ \phi \triangledown^{2}\phi => \triangledown\phi \cdot \triangledown\phi  + A $

where $A$ ultimately results in 0

Comment: o I just realized there's a negative, so ϕ▽2ϕ has to change into - ▽ϕ⋅▽ϕ

Comment: Hi, not sure if this helps but by glancing at your equations this one $\phi \triangledown^{2}\phi => \triangledown\phi \cdot \triangledown\phi$ strikes me a chain rule. Maybe the hidden term vanishes from the integration it's in.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right. Sad I can't do anything other than giving you an upvote.

Comment: $\nabla\cdot \nabla \phi^2 = 2 \phi \nabla^2 \phi + 2 \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi$. Next use the divergence theorem  and drop a boundary term in  view of the fact the integrand vanishes sufficiently fast (the static field generated by a charged bounded region)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of having an answer: In $\phi \nabla ^2 \phi$, consider the term $\phi \frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}$. By the product rule, this is equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\phi \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right) - \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2$. Combining all three terms, we get $\phi \nabla^2 \phi = \nabla\cdot \left(\phi \nabla \phi\right) - \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi$. Upon integrating, the first terms turns into a surface integral over all space. Since $\phi$ goes as $1/r$, $\phi \nabla \phi$ goes as $1/r^3$, and since the surface element goes as $r^2$, the integral is zero when $r \to \infty$. Therefore we're left with $- \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi$, that is, $-E^2$.